# Fastest way to get a certificate of no marriage to Belgium

Tags: belgium, philippine-citizens

What is the fastest way to get a certificate of no marriage from the Philippines to Belgium?

Is it possible to obtain it in Belgium?
If not what is the fastest to get it send from the Philippines to Belgium?

Going to the Philippines and flying back with the certificate is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to transport a document is to have the document carried by a human passenger, flying from the Philippines to Belgium. This can be accomplished with a flight duration (including layovers) of less than 24 hours.

Second-fastest would be to use an international courier such as DHL or FedEx. A brief look at their websites suggests this would take between several days and a week.